# Como declarar una condicional ( if ) con un wchar_t en winapi y c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, condiciones, winapi

Estoy haciendo un programa en winapi el cual contara con una ventana para que el usuario se registre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que cuando el usuario le de en "continuar" se verifique que el usuario no haya dejado alguna casilla en blanco, para ello se me ocurrió guardar el contenido del edit control (ó editbox) en una variable tipo wchar_t y después verificar si esta vacío con ayuda de la condicional if y la función lenght o empty.

El problema es que me da el siguiente error, tanto con la función lenght como con empty. Ya antes había usado ambas funciones pero solo con variables tipo string.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente de varias formas pero nada. Me podrían decir como solucionarlo o en que me estoy equivocando? gracias de antemano.

```
case IDC_BUTTON2: {
        wchar_t fotoENT[200];
        wchar_t nombreENT[60];
        wchar_t empresaENT[35];
        wchar_t usernameENT[25];
        wchar_t passwordENT[30];
        
        SendMessage(GetDlgItem(ventana, IDC_EDIT3), WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(nombreENT) / sizeof(nombreENT[0]), (LPARAM)nombreENT);

        if (nombreENT.length() == 0){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el número de caracteres devueltos en el array, puedes usar la función `wcslen`. También puedes coger el valor devuelto por `SendMessage`, que es justamente el número de caracteres copiados en el caso de `WM_GETTEXT`.

Answer (score 1):

El error es claro y conciso: "*La expresión debe tener un tipo de clase*". Aunque admito que la traducción del error desde inglés deja bastante que desear, yo habría traducido dicho error como "*La expresión debe tener una clase como tipo*".

¿Por qué sucede ese error? Porque estás usando el operador punto (`.`), dicho operador sirve para acceder a miembros de objetos siendo lo que hay a la izquierda del punto el objeto y a la derecha del punto el miembro al que se quiere acceder... pero `nombreENT` no es un objeto, es una formación<sup>1</sup> de 60 caracteres anchos:

```
wchar_t nombreENT[60];
```

Posiblemente, lo que querías era una cadena de caracteres, es decir:

```
std::wstring fotoENT;
std::wstring nombreENT;
std::wstring empresaENT;
std::wstring usernameENT;
std::wstring passwordENT;
```

Lo cuál sí es un objeto y sí dispone del miembro [`length`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size).

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.